# How to i get a marker (or pin) on a specified location for google maps?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

This is the link that i was using for google map with one marker on a specific latitude and longitude. But with this code, i get two markers. An arrow on specific address i wanted and a pin at the center of the town or city of that address. May i know what is wrong here? I want just one pin on specific address, not on the city center. This is for asp.net application.

**Edited:**

http://maps.google.com/maps?key=ABQIAAAAyzfPKfpu4h_2V2EY0MQKcBQLL4oEiRrONF_Oyv5y1AbK0VEmMxQN1Z5_-BmLvlLLFYiLTknmwufmIg&mapclient=jsapi&ie=UTF8&spn=0.222565,0.596008&z=14&q=35.599843,-80.8495&output=embed

I really appreciate all your help. Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: Ummm your link is drowning us in Mediterranean sea :)

Comment: I had not given lat and long there. Let me update with correct lat and long..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps tries to mark any other noteworthy places in the area. There are a couple methods you can use to stop this. 
One method is to add `loc:` to your GPS query like this:

http://maps.google.com/maps?key=ABQIAAAAyzfPKfpu4h_2V2EY0MQKcBQLL4oEiRrONF_Oyv5y1AbK0VEmMxQN1Z5_-BmLvlLLFYiLTknmwufmIg&mapclient=jsapi&ie=UTF8&spn=0.222565,0.596008&z=14&q=loc:35.599843,-80.8495&output=embed

You can do the same thing but add a description to the label by adding `[desc]@` like this:

http://maps.google.com/maps?key=ABQIAAAAyzfPKfpu4h_2V2EY0MQKcBQLL4oEiRrONF_Oyv5y1AbK0VEmMxQN1Z5_-BmLvlLLFYiLTknmwufmIg&mapclient=jsapi&ie=UTF8&spn=0.222565,0.596008&z=14&q=Remo@35.599843,-80.8495%29&output=embed

For future reference, [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) explains various Google Maps parameters.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide  your link to the parameters is 404

Comment: @CheGueVerra - Thanks for letting me know, I've updated it with yours.